# Installing a Windows service to run as virtual user

Tags: .net, windows-services, installation

I have a [`ServiceProcessInstaller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceprocessinstaller.aspx) which installs a .NET Windows Service.

The install process works perfectly if I either:

- Set the service to run as SYSTEM (`serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem`).
- Set the service to run as a normal user (`serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = ServiceAccount.User`) by either specifying the `Username` and `Password` properties, or letting the install process prompt me.

However, I would like the service to run as a virtual user, *a la* `NT Service\ServiceName`. If you look at the some of the SQL Server services, you will see they default to log on as their own virtual user account. There is more, albeit limited, information at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548356.aspx.

---

I have tried setting `serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = @"NT Service\ServiceName"`, but the installer then throws the following error no matter what I give as the password (I have tried `String.Empty`, same as the user name, my own password, `null` to bring up the interactive dialog, and even random junk):

> No mapping between account names and security IDs was done

However, if I install the service normally (e.g. run as SYSTEM), I can then go in to the service's properties from the `services.msc` snap-in, on the Log On page change the user to `NT Service\ServiceName`, and it works beautifully.

I have also looked into the [`ChangeServiceConfig2` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I can't seem to get it to change anything either.

---

How can I set the log on user to the virtual user `NT Service\ServiceName` from code within my `ServiceProcessInstaller`?

Comment: Managed and virtual service accounts are a pretty new Windows feature.  You'll need to ask questions about it at a site like serverfault.com, the kind of place where you'll find sysadmins that tinker with this.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548356%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant I realize it's a bit borderline, but my question was specifically about how to set the user from code, as I could clearly set the user manually. As such I thought it was more a programming question than a sysadmin question and posted here. There also seemed to be more questions on SO about installing a service than SF - not that it means much I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it directly with the `ServiceProcessInstaller` object. However, you can set the username after the service is installed, in the `ServiceInstaller.Committed` event, using [the Change method in WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384901). Specify the username as `wmiParams[6]` and *leave the password null*:

```
void serviceInstaller1_Committed(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
{
    using (ManagementObject service = new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath("Win32_Service.Name='ServiceName'")))
    {
        object[] wmiParams = new object[11];
        wmiParams[6] = @"NT Service\ServiceName";
        service.InvokeMethod("Change", wmiParams);
    }
}
```

Finally, don't forget to give the user read/execute permission on your service exe and config files, or you will get an Access Denied error.

Comment: In case you're a dummy like me, it's actually important that the name of the account you give in the `wmiParams[6]` line match your service name.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to the solution suggested above (using `ServiceInstaller.Committed` event) is described as workaround on [connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/795196/service-process-installer-should-support-virtual-service-accounts). The idea is to tweak a private field `haveLoginInfo` via reflection to allow `null` as valid password.

```
    const string s_ServiceName = "myservice1";
    const string s_DisplayName = "Tell admin what it is";
    const string s_Description = "Tell admin what it does";

        var procesServiceInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller
        {
            Account = ServiceAccount.User,
            Username = string.Format("NT Service\\{0}", s_ServiceName),
            Password = null,
        };

        //Here comes the hack.
        // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
        procesServiceInstaller
            .GetType()
            .GetField("haveLoginInfo", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .SetValue(procesServiceInstaller, true);



        var serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
        var path = string.Format(
              "/assemblypath={0}",
              Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string[] cmdline = { path };

        var context = new InstallContext("", cmdline);
        serviceInstaller.Context = context;
        serviceInstaller.DisplayName = s_DisplayName;
        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = s_ServiceName;
        serviceInstaller.Description = s_Description;
        serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual;
        serviceInstaller.Parent = procesServiceInstaller;

        try
        {
            var state = new ListDictionary();
            serviceInstaller.Install(state);
        }
        catch (Win32Exception win32Exception)
        {
            //TODO: HandleException(win32Exception); 
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            //TODO: HandleException(ex);
        }
```

Even this solution is not less hacky, at least it's visually less ugly.

NOTE: There is a mistake in the workaround description at [connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/795196/service-process-installer-should-support-virtual-service-accounts). The private field name mentioned there is `hasLoginInfo` but must be `haveLoginInfo`.